# Dynamically Appending Object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm building a chat application where I have conversations and messages, which are stored as respective objects. The messages are bundled according to the conversation that they belong to. So when I push messages, they're being pushed under their conversation's Id.

I have the following implementation :

```
allMsgs = {
    ...allMsgs,
    [payload.conversationId]: {
        ...payload.message 
    }
}
```

I am able to add and categorize the messages into their respective conversations but not bundle the messages themselves. The last message is always overwriting the contents -which are the messages- of each conversationId. So I'm left with allMsgs having multiple conversatinIds but one message in each conversationId. This seems like such a duh thing but I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a duh thing

```
state.allMsgs = {
    ...state.allMsgs,
    [payload.conversationId]: {
        ...state.allMsgs[payload.conversationId],
        [payload.message.id]: payload.message
    }
}
```